# Linking excel data source with obiee analysis

Tags: excel, oracle, oracle12c, analysis, obiee

I am using OBIEE 12c and recently I created a data source from excel file using Visual Analyzer. I used this data source for creating analysis and it worked correctly. 
However, when I wanted to create an action link from this data source column to the other analysis in obiee created using another subject area, I got  wrong results. So my question is, does OBIEE support action links between data sources created in VA and subject areas created in Admin Tool? If yes, how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean "wrong results"? And the rules are the same as for anything: data must be a perfect match.

Comment: When action link opens the second analysis, I don't get results corresponding the value that has been sent by the action link, I just get the whole analysis. I did the same between subject areas and it worked fine. But between analysis created from  Excel data set and analysis of Subject area, I dont see this interaction. Data type, values match, the only thing is difference in column name

Comment: I had thoughts on changing the column name and make them same. However, when I upload excel file after changes, VA reads column name(which is in Cyrillic) wrong that is I see random symbols instead of the word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table/column names do not match then the vanilla interaction will never work.

You will have to go for the GoURL approach: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/biee/BIEIT/apiwebintegrate.htm#BIEIT355